# Changing Font for Unordered List for Swift NSAttributedString

Tags: html, ios, swift, html-lists, nsattributedstring

I am attempting to create an NSAttributedString out of an HTML string, but I have to change the font of the string. I was able to successfully achieve this by doing:

```
let myOriginalString: String = "<!DOCTYPE html>
                    <head>
                      <style type=\"text/css\">
                        body{font-family: '-apple-system','Avenir-Medium',`Avenir-Black`; font-size:14;}
                      </style>
                    <body>
                      My HTML content
                    </body>"

let data: Data = myOriginalString.data(using: .utf8)

let myConvertedString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
```

When `myConvertedString` is rendered on the screen, the text is in the correct font.

But when I attempt to do the same conversion where the HTML body contains an **unordered list**, the content in the unordered list is not in the format I specified:

```
let myOriginalString: String = "<!DOCTYPE html>
                    <head>
                      <style type=\"text/css\">
                        body{font-family: '-apple-system','Avenir-Medium',`Avenir-Black`; font-size:14;}
                      </style>
                    <body>
                      My HTML content
                      <ul>
                        <li>Item 1</li>
                        <li>Item 2</li>
                      </ul>
                    </body>"

let data: Data = myOriginalString.data(using: .utf8)

let myConvertedString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
```

When `myConvertedString` is rendered on the screen, the string `My HTML Content` is of the correct format, but `Item 1` and `Item 2` are not in the font I specified.

I attempted to add styling for both the `ul` tag and the `li` tag, but same result.

Why is NSAttributedString rendering all the text with the correct font, except for unordered list? Is there a better way to create an unordered list with an NSAttributedString instead of using html?

Comment: Maybe the lack of closing tag for each item is messing it up somehow?

Comment: Oops, sorry that was a typ0. I have the closing tags there in my actual code. I've fixed the question.

Comment: Your CSS is invalid (unless it's a typo): replace the back ticks with single quotes around `Avenir-Black`; and give a unit to `font-size`: `font-size: 14pt;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better solution than using an HTML unordered list by using NSMutableParagraphStyle instead:

```
let myAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

// Create a paragraph style
let paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
            paragraphStyle.tabStops = [NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: 10, options: [:])]
            paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
            paragraphStyle.headIndent = 10

let item1 =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\u{2022} Item1\n\n", attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0), .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle])

let item2 =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\u{2022} Item2\n\n", attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0), .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle])

myAttributedString.append(item1)
myAttributedString.append(item2)
```

Now `myAttributedString` prints out `item1` and `item2` in the correct font with the proper styling (wrapped words don't have same minx value as bullet point)

I think the incorrect font the HTML portion was occurring because I was trying to create an NSAttributedString that consisted some normal NSAttributedString, an HTML NSAttributedString, followed by more normal NSAttributedStrings. I don't think this should be an issue, perhaps it's a bug???

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it with Arial and it works:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myOriginalString = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 32px;
            color: red;
        }
        </style>
        <body>
        My HTML content
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
        </body>
        """

        if let data = myOriginalString.data(using: .utf8) {

            if let converted = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil) {

                textView.attributedText = converted
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try appending two (one before and one after) non-html styled NSAttributedStrings to your `converted` NSAttributedString  and see if you still get the same result...